# Legend oculto por defecto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `legend` que cuando cargo la página está abierto por defecto y lo que necesito es todo lo contrario, que al cargar la página esté oculto y si necesito abrirlo darle click.

Mi código es:

```js
$(function() {
  // Set cursor to pointer and add click function
  $("legend").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function() {
    var legend = $(this);
    var value = $(this).children("span").html();
    if (value == "[-]")
      value = "[+]";
    else
      value = "[-]";
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow", function() {
      legend.children("span").html(value);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<legend class="section" style="color:#0CF">Contact Info <span>[-]</span></legend>
```

Comment: Publica el html/css correspondiente para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Deberías añadir el HTML para poder ver el escenario completo de tu problema. Por otro lado, parece que te falta un `.` o un `#` en la primera llamada a jQuery

Comment: @PabloLozano Supongo que se estará refiriendo a la etiqueta `legend` por lo que no sería una clase o un ID.

Comment: Efectivamente, tal y como he editado, es una etiqueta.

Comment: No recordaba esta etiqueta! Gracias, por el aporte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería bastar con que le pongas el estilo de escondido a los elementos hermanos que quieres que aparezcan escondidos, así:

```
<legend class="section" style="color:#0CF">Contact Info <span>[+]</span></legend>
<div style="display:none;">Información adicional</div>
```

Con jQuery, también podrías simular el primer clic luego de registrar el evento, así:

```
$("legend").css("cursor","pointer").click(function(){
    // ...
}).click();
```

Comment: de esta manera ya lo probé pero me desaparece el texto "Contact Info" por eso creo que el tema está en ponerlo en jQuery

Comment: No había leído bien lo que hacía tu código. Actualicé mi respuesta para darte una mejor opción con estilos, o la opción que pides de jQuery

Comment: Hola @Piyin ahora funciona bien pero me cierra todos los legends... sabes si hay alguna manera de que cierre ciertos legends. Es que hay apartados que si me interesa que queden abiertos y otros cerrados.

Comment: Correcto todo!!! muchas gracias @Piyin